# Python: cmap argument in matplotlib imshow() generates different binary images

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

Binary images are shown correctly by setting cmap="gray".

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
square = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.imshow(square, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

However when we change it to "binary", imshow() generate the inverse image!

```
plt.imshow(square, cmap="binary")
```

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of the [Colormap reference of the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html):

[image]

As can be seen `binary` starts at white and goes to black, while `gray` starts at black and goes to white.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know the reason for such choices?

Comment: Not sure what "such choices" would refer to.

Comment: Is there a historical reason that library developers for binary camp choose 0 as white and 1 as black? However in image processing it is common to use the inverse setting. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: In general there should be at least the two options of black->white and white->black. Then the question is how to name those. In principle, you can name one "gray" and the other "gray_r". But the `_r` syntax isn't very discoverable for users, so one can think of a better name. "binary" makes sense because 0 is usually nothing (=white), while 1 is something, (=black).

Answer (score 2):

You can check the below `matplotlib` colormaps, where binary is inverse of gray and that's why you are getting above result.

[image]

Read more about it from [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Show_colormaps.html#matplotlib-show-colormaps).